Load deep nested schema using JSchema
I have a huge JSON schema with a part of it looking like this:
{
   "if":{
      "required":[
         "product_category"
      ],
      "properties":{
         "product_category":{
            "contains":{
               "required":[
                  "value"
               ],
               "properties":{
                  "value":{
                     "enum":[
                        "20005000"
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "then":{
      "properties":{
         "product_subcategory":{
            "items":{
               "properties":{
                  "value":{
                     "enum":[
                        "20005085",
                        "20005088",
                        "20005065",
                        "20005068",
                        "20005401",
                        "20005115",
                        "20005118",
                        "20005010",
                        "20005505",
                        "20005105",
                        "20005108",
                        "20005135"
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "else":{
      "if":{
         "required":[
            "product_category"
         ],
         "properties":{
            "product_category":{
               "contains":{
                  "required":[
                     "value"
                  ],
                  "properties":{
                     "value":{
                        "enum":[
                           "20055000"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "then":{
         "properties":{
            "product_subcategory":{
               "items":{
                  "properties":{
                     "value":{
                        "enum":[
                           "20055005",
                           "20055010",
                           "20055015",
                           "20055020",
                           "20055040",
                           "20055045",
                           "20055050",
                           "20055075",
                           "20055085",
                           "20055090",
                           "20055095",
                           "20055100",
                           "20055110"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "else":{
         "if":{
            "required":[
               "product_category"
            ],
            "properties":{
               "product_category":{
                  "contains":{
                     "required":[
                        "value"
                     ],
                     "properties":{
                        "value":{
                           "enum":[
                              "20056000"
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "then":{
            "properties":{
               "product_subcategory":{
                  "items":{
                     "properties":{
                        "value":{
                           "enum":[
                              "20056010",
                              "20056005",
                              "20056050",
                              "20056020",
                              "20056025",
                              "20056100",
                              "20056070",
                              "20056090",
                              "20056040",
                              "20056035",
                              "20056030"
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  }
               },
               "else":{
                  "if":"more nested if-then-else here"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

I want to call JSchema.Load() on it. The problem is that depth of that JSON exceeds default MaxDepth = 64 and Load() method throws Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderExceptio. My code looks like this:
using (var stringReader = new StringReader(json))
using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
{
    var schema = JSchema.Load(jsonReader);
}

I've tried to set JsonTextReader.MaxDepth to 256 but then I get StackOverflowException.
I wrote custom JsonTextReader implementation which shouldn't go deeper after reaching maxDepth:
class DepthLimitingJsonReader : JsonTextReader
    {
        private readonly int _maxDepth;
        private int _currentDepth;

        public DepthLimitingJsonReader(TextReader reader, int maxDepth)
            : base(reader)
        {
            _maxDepth = maxDepth;
            _currentDepth = 0;
        }

        public override bool Read()
        {
            bool result = base.Read();

            if (result)
            {
                if (TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject || TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
                {
                    _currentDepth++;
                    // If depth exceeds maxDepth, skip the content inside this object or array
                    if (_currentDepth > _maxDepth && Path.EndsWith("else"))
                    {
                        Skip();
                    }
                }
                else if (TokenType == JsonToken.EndObject || TokenType == JsonToken.EndArray)
                {
                    _currentDepth--;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

But anyway Skip() method process tokens deeply within the structure and still exceptions are thrown. I want ignore everything what is deeper than maxDepth. How can I do that?

Is there any chance you could [edit] your question to share a [mcve] with well-formed JSON?  It doesn't have to be your actual schema, just something that is well-formed (e.g. no parse errors from https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and reproduces the StackOverflowException at MaxDepth 256.  Thanks!
